# Remember dynamic select options in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

**Models:**

User create Event, and each Event need a Court location, then a House location, the value of House depends on the value of Court, for example:

select Court A, returns House as A1, A2, A3

select Court B, returns House as B1, B2, B3

**In Event Controller form:**

```
def new
  @event = current_user.events.build(event_params)
  @courts = Court.all
  @houses = House.where("court_id = ?", Court.first.id)
end

def edit
  @event = Event.find(params[:id])
  @courts = Court.where(:id => @event.court_id)
  @houses = House.where(:id => @event.house_id)
end
```

**In View form:**

```
<%= f.label 'Event Location' %>
<%= f.select :court_id, options_for_select(@courts.collect { |court| [court.name, court.id] }, 1), {}, { id: 'courts_select' } %>
<%= f.select :house_id, options_for_select(@houses.collect { |house| [house.name, house.id] }, 0), {}, { id: 'houses_select' } %>
```

**Javascript:**

```
$(function() {
  return $(document).on('change', '#courts_select', function(evt) {
    return $.ajax('/events/update_houses', {
      type: 'GET',
      dataType: 'script',
      data: {
        court_id: $("#courts_select option:selected").val()
      },
      error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        return console.log("AJAX Error: " + textStatus);
      },
      success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        return console.log("Dynamic court select OK!");
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Now this works fine when the user create the event, but when they want to edit, the Court and House Select only shows 1 value. It's because in the edit controller the *where()* only returns 1 value. How can I change my edit controller code so that at edit form, it returns the a list of choices and remembers the user's choice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For starters, you want to supply all Courts and the corresponding Houses for the currently-selected Court.

```
def edit
  @event = Event.find(params[:id])
  @courts = Court.all
  @houses = House.where(:court_id => @event.court_id)
end
```

Then you want your selects to select the proper value from the dropdown. Instead of:

```
<%= f.select :court_id, options_for_select(@courts.collect { |court| [court.name, court.id] }, 1), {}, { id: 'courts_select' } %>
```

Something like:

```
<%= f.select :court_id, options_for_select(@courts.collect { |court| [court.name, court.id] }, @event.court_id), {}, { id: 'courts_select' } %>
```

... rinse and repeat for the House select

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you so much. Now just a side question, if you were to design a simple system like this, would you have done this way? Creating separate court and house model and using javascript do the selecting? What other different approach would you've done?

Comment: I think I would have done it like you did. Maybe someone else can chime in with different/better solution?